# How to avoid loading common library for included template in jinja2

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

I am loading jquery in main template.
And this main template include header.html template.
I want to use jquery in header.html without loading it again as I loaded it in main template.
But it doesn't work.

This is main.html template

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
<div> ... content here </div>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
// my some script here
</script>
```

This is header.html

```
<div> ... header content here </div>
<script>

  $(function () {
     alert('This is not working...');
 });
</script>
```

Should I load jquery in header.html again?
Thanks

Comment: Move your jquery script include *before* the header include

Comment: sorry can you post main.html and header.html? thanks

Comment: No.  Literally take your script jquery include line and put it before your header.html include line

Answer (score 1):

I just moved your jQuery include up above your header.

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
{% include 'header.html' %}
<div> ... content here </div>
<script> 
// my some script here
</script>
```